# Chaining API calls

Tags: ios, swift, api, asynchronous

I've built myself an APIService class, handling all interaction with APIs my App is using

```swift
func callEndpointX(token: String, completion: @escaping(Result<User, APIError>) -> Void) {
        guard let endpoint = URL(string: apiBaseUrl + "/endpointX") else {fatalError()}
        var request = URLRequest(url: endpoint)
        request.addValue("Bearer " + token, forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
        request.httpMethod = "GET"

        let dataTask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            guard let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpResponse.statusCode == 200, let jsonData = data
                else { ... completion(.failure(.responseError)); return }
            do {
                let response = try JSONDecoder()...
                completion(.success(response.detailresponse!))
            } catch {
                ...
                completion(.failure(.decodingError))
            }
        }
        dataTask.resume()
    }
```

My challenge is that the Bearer **Tokens** I'm passing along do **expire**. What I **would like to** do in case of an expired token is to **silently refresh** the token for the user before hitting the api.
So I've got a mini function `func tokenExpired() -> Bool {...}` checking if the Token has alreaady expired and I have access to another API all `refreshToken` in a similar way as `func callEndpointX` above.

What I'm struggling with is how to chain these together to **avoid race conditions** - i.e. when `func callEndpointX` gets called, it should check `func tokenExpired()` and not continue any other work until that's done. If expired, it should first execute `refreshToken` and only after that returns continue with finally executing the ret of `func callEndpointX`.

All this chaining is messing with my brain and I was hoping someone would be able to guide me here.

Many thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

A solution is to call recursively callEndPointX after token refresh is completed.
Assume your token request is like this:

```
func requestToken(completion:@escaping((String) -> Void))
```

then

```
func callEndpointX(token: String, completion: @escaping(Result<User, APIError>) -> Void) {
       if tokenExpired() {
            requestToken(completion: { newToken in
                 callEndpointX(token: newToken, completion: completion)
            })
       }
       else {
          // your code for callendpointX
       }
}
```